# Can res.locals Be Accessed By Clients?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, server

**Context**

I am storing the entire user object in `res.locals.loggedUser` like this in the server:

```
app.use(async (req, res, next) => {
     const user = await User.findById(req.session.userid);
     res.locals.loggedUser = user;

     next();
});
```

After setting `res.locals.loggedUser`, I can access it through `ejs` in client side like this:

```
<% if(loggedUser) { %>
     <p>Your name: <%= loggedUser.name %></p>
<% } %>
```

The entire user object consists of these fields:

```
    _id: {
        ObjectId("123abc")
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Your name is required.']
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Email cannot be blank.'],
        unique: true
    },
    phone: {
        type: Number,
        required: [true, 'You must provide your phone number.'],
        unique: true
    },
    hashpassword: String,
    date: {
        joined: {
            type: Date
        }
    },
```

**Question**

Can clients get access to the rest of the fields of the user object like the `hashpassword` field? Or is `res.locals` only available to the server?

*Thank You!*

Comment: ejs is generally executed by the server. Are you sure you have client-side ejs?

Comment: @AKX Yes, I have index.ejs file which is served to the clients. It is written in HTML and has those snippets of ejs syntax for dynamic inputs.

Comment: @AKX I have the ejs-mate package downloaded through NPM. Then, the template engine is set like this: app.engine('ejs', ejsMate);

Comment: Right. That's rendered on the server, so the clients only ever get whatever you render out. If you don't expose the password hash, it's not exposed.

Comment: Thank you! I understand it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can res.locals Be Accessed By Clients?

No.

`res.locals` exists only on the server - it is not available to the client.

The contents of `res.locals` can be used by your server-side template/template engine in building a web page like you already do with `<% if(loggedUser) { %>` that will be sent to the client, but there will be nothing from `res.locals` in the web page unless you specifically add something to your template that inserts something from `res.locals` into the web page.

Comment: Does the same apply for app.locals?

Comment: @user15344186 - Yes.  Same.  The client only gets access to two things, http headers you set in the http response and the contents of the web page you build and send to them.  Everything else is just server-side state and temporary local variables that only exists on the server.

Comment: Ok I understand now thanks!